# How to find Python 3's home and dll path installed by pyenv on Ubuntu?

Tags: python, ubuntu, vim, environment, pyenv

When use vim's insert mode, it happened:

```
/home/user/.vim/plugged/ultisnips/autoload/UltiSnips.vim Error:
E319: Sorry, can't use: py3 import vim
```

Because now using this plugin:

```
Plug 'SirVer/ultisnips'
```

I installed `Python3` by `pyenv`.

```
$ pyenv versions
  system
* 3.9.1 (set by /home/user/.pyenv/version)
$ which python
/home/user/.pyenv/shims/python
$ python -V
Python 3.9.1
```

When use macOS, set these items into `~/.vimrc` can resolve the problem:

```
set pythonthreedll=/usr/local/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/Python
set pythonthreehome=/usr/local/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9
```

But on Ubuntu, how to find `pythongthreehome` and `pythonthreedll` path? I tried to set `/home/user/.pyenv/shims/python`, not work.

Comment: Yes, I installed `vim-now`. It works now. Could you write it as an answer? I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is most likely that you have a Vim package without Python enabled.

You can tell that from the `vim --version` output (or `:version` inside Vim.) If it says `+python3` or `+python3/dyn`, then it means Python is enabled. On the other hand, if it says `-python3`, then it doesn't.

If your Vim has Python disabled, you will need to install a different Vim package. On Ubuntu or Debian, you could use `apt-get install vim-nox` to install a Vim package which has Python enabled.